# if statement causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a cache simulator, and for some reason, my if statements keep giving me segfaults. For debugging purposes, I've added some print statements. Everything prints exactly the way I expect it to, up until just before the if statement, and then it just spits back `Segmentation Fault`.

```
int find_set(node** cache, unsigned set_i, long t, int E) {
  printf("finding set\n");
  int i; // index
  for (i = 0; i < E; i++) {
    printf("trying seti = %d and i = %d \n", set_i, i);
    printf("cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit = %d\n", cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit);
    printf("cache[set_i][i]->tag = %d\n", cache[set_i][i]->tag);
    if (cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit == 1) && ((cache[set_i][i]->tag) == t) {
      printf("found tag! \n");
      cache[set_i][i]->LRU_count = 0; // just used
      return i; // index of the set we found
    }
  }
  return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: Is it the only code in your program?

Comment: There's no way I know of that `if` statement by itself will generate a segmentation fault.  It's probably a line near it that's doing it. You need to show more of your code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: No, the rest of the program runs fine. This part is in a for loop. Is there any reason that an if statement would bug out like this?

Comment: @fourforrea No, unless you've redefined `printf` or are not giving us the real code--eg, if one of the `1`s tested is actually computed by accessing a pointer that may be invalid, then that would cause this. In short, `if` statements do not "bug out".

Comment: No, the rest of your code doesn't run fine, unless you're running a really bad shareware compiler which doesn't properly compile the very simple line of code you're showing, or as @Saposhiente says, you've redefined `printf` somewhere . Many times the inexperienced programmer *thinks* the fault is at a particular line, but it's really caused either by the line after, or some other place in the code which has a latent effect.

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error somewhere - there's one extra right brace (`}`). Can you fix the braces so it's understood what groups properly with what?

Comment: I was correct in thinking it wasn't the real code. I assume the line number indicates that the problem is in line `if (cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit == 1) &&`? If so, then the pointer at `cache[set_i][i]` is not a valid `node`; this could either be because `cache` is set incorrectly or because a value of `set_i` or `i` is incorrect.

Comment: How is `node` defined? If it's not `typedef`ed as a pointer, then anything that looks like, `cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit` is a problem. Do you know how large `i` and `set_i` are getting in your loop, and that they don't exceed the allocated memory? How was the memory for the `cache` data structure allocated? Many novice programmers get dynamic allocation of a 2-dimensional array wrong.

Comment: It is most likely the assignment

Comment: If there was a problem with the cache structure or the value of i or set_i, it wouldn't be able to evaluate to print properly.

Answer (score 0):

At very least, get your parentheses and curly braces to line up.  I removed one end curly brace, and fixed the parentheses after the if.  Try replacing your function with this:

```
int find_set(node** cache, unsigned set_i, long t, int E){
  printf("finding set\n");
  int i; //index                                                             
  int val;
  for (i = 0; i < E; i++){
    printf("trying seti = %d and i = %d \n",set_i,i);
    printf("cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit = %d\n",cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit);
    printf("cache[set_i][i]->tag = %d\n",cache[set_i][i]->tag);
    if ((cache[set_i][i]->valid_bit == 1) && (cache[set_i][i]->tag == t)){
      printf("found tag! \n");
      cache[set_i][i]->LRU_count = 0; //just used                          
      return i; //index of the set we found                                
    }
  }
  return -1; //not found                                                     
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a Segmentation Error.

Comment: Comment out the for loop (lines 5 through 14 in my code).  Does it run without an error?  If it does, it will return -1.  If it doesn't there's something else wrong in the program.